# Translation Memory in Poedit and Gettext as a solution to update .po files automatically

Tags: gettext, poedit, po

As you probably know, there's an option in Poedit (under Catalog menu) called "Automatically Translate Using TM" (TM = Translation Memory). TM stores already translated strings in a database located on `~/.local/share/poedit/TM` directory.

The questions are:

- How can I generate and reuse such a TM database from command line interface?
- Regardless of Poedit, does Gettext itself offer such a functionality? Is there a way to ask `msginit` for example to use a TM?

I think such a function could be the best way to update `.po` files from the source file efficiently.